# binary tree printing out with vector duplicate value

Tags: c++

I am trying to hold vector to gather all the duplicate values in binary tree.

if binary tree has 2, 2, 5,6,7,7,8, then it would print out 2 and 7 with vector.

I realized with my recursion 
1. it will only bring 2 values at most as it resets the vector every time it calls the function
2. At the end of recursive function - it does not bring any value

What am I missing in my recursive function?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    node *left, *right;
};

node* getnew(int val) {
    node *curr = new node;
    curr->data = val;
    curr->left = curr->right = nullptr;
    return curr;
}


node* insert(node* root, int val) {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return getnew(val);
    if (val > root->data) 
        root->right = insert(root->right, val);
    else if (val <= root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, val);
    return root;
}

void print(node*root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        print(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        print(root->right);
    }
}


int assist(node* root, int value) {
    if(root!=nullptr){
    if (root->data == value)return value;
    return assist(root->left, value) || assist(root->right, value);
    }
    else return -5;
}

vector<int> findmode(node* root) {
    vector<int> thedup;
    //create recusion that find dup value
    //we need assistant function to find dup value
    if (root != nullptr) {
        if(assist(root->left, root->data)!=-5){
            thedup.push_back(root->data);
            return thedup;
        }
        else if(assist(root->right, root->data)!=-5){
            thedup.push_back(root->data);
        return thedup;
        }
        return thedup;
    }
    else return thedup;
}

int main() {
    node *root = nullptr;


    root = insert(root, 5);
    insert(root, 3);
    insert(root, 2);
    insert(root, 4);
    insert(root, 2);
    insert(root, 2);
    insert(root, 8);


    print(root);

    cout << endl;
    vector<int> test;

    for (int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++)
        cout << test[i] << " " << endl;

}
```

Comment: Hint -- The way you solve this is to supply additional arguments (such as the vector) to the traversal function `assist`.  Fill in the information in `assist`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a revised example that will traverse the tree, and then use the tree itself as an index to look for duplicates. As mentioned in the comment, you need to pass your collector by reference to avoid overwriting it. I've updated your solution to use a `set` instead of a vector to avoid adding duplicates (which would happen with a vector).  The updated code is below (with some commented out debugging statements), and you can also give it a try at https://repl.it/@cptndave/btreedups.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    node *left, *right;
};

node* getnew(int val) {
    node *curr = new node;
    curr->data = val;
    curr->left = curr->right = nullptr;
    // printf("New %p %d\n", curr, val);
    return curr;
}


node* insert(node* root, int val) {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return getnew(val);
    if (val > root->data) 
        root->right = insert(root->right, val);
    else if (val <= root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, val);
    return root;
}

void print(node*root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        print(root->left);
        cout << root->data << " ";
        print(root->right);
    }
}

// Return true if data exists outside of ignore node
bool exists(node *root, node *target)
{
  if (root == nullptr)
    return false;
  // printf("  Looking for %d at %p\n", target->data, root);
  if (root != target && root->data == target->data)
    return true;
  if (target->data > root->data)
    return exists(root->right, target);
  else
    return exists(root->left, target);
}

// Traverse tree looking for duplicates
void finddup_helper(node *root, node *current, set<int> *dups)
{
  if (current == nullptr)
    return;
  // printf("Helper: root %p, current: %p, %d\n",  root, current, current->data);
  if (exists(root, current)) {
    // printf("dup %d\n", current->data);
    dups->insert(current->data);
  }
  finddup_helper(root, current->left, dups);
  finddup_helper(root, current->right, dups);
}

// Base function which kicks off helper from the root
set<int> finddups(node *root)
{
  set<int> dups;
  finddup_helper(root, root, &dups);
  return dups;
}

int main() {
    node *root = nullptr;

    root = insert(root, 5);
    insert(root, 3);
    insert(root, 2);
    insert(root, 4);
    insert(root, 2);
    insert(root, 2);
    insert(root, 8);
    insert(root, 5);

    cout << "Tree: ";
    print(root);

    cout << endl;
    set<int> dups = finddups(root);;

    cout << "Duplicates: ";
    for (set<int>::iterator it = dups.begin(); it != dups.end(); it++)
      cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```